# Reductive groups over arbitrary fields with disconnected relative root systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a connected reductive group over a field $k$, not necessarily algebraically closed.  Let $\Phi$ be the relative root system for $\mathbf{G}$ with respect to $k$, and assume that $\Phi$ is disconnected with connected components $\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_r$.  If $k$ was algebraically closed, then the group $\mathbf{G}$ basically decomposes as the direct product of factors corresponding to the $\Phi_i$.  Here "basically" means modulo things involving e.g. centers of various groups (for simplicity, I don't want to write out the precise statement).

**Question**: To what extent does something like this hold in general?

I'm really only comfortable working over algebraically closed fields, but for a paper I'm writing it would be very helpful to be able to work more generally.  Unfortunately, all the sources I've consulted don't seem to spell the above out (maybe it's easy if you really understand things?).  References would be very useful.

Comment: It seems Ngo's notes https://math.uchicago.edu/~ngo/takagi.pdf has detailed exposition on root data over non-algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki: There are an uncountable number of surveys that discuss this kind of material (my favorite is https://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/courses/algp.pdf).  But as far as I can tell none of them (including the notes you mention, which are mostly about other things) address the basic issue in my question (which happens to be exactly the issue standing in the way of me completing my paper -- I might have a followup question later that will help me get sharper results, but the question in this post will get me 90% of the way there).

Comment: Semi-simple groups have unique decompositions and connected components, whereas tori have many decompositions. A decomposition of a root system into a direct sum of Galois invariant root systems induces a product decomposition of the group over the ground field. This follows formally from uniqueness: the product of the two groups would also have this same root system. Thus the factors of a semi-simple group are the minimal Galois invariant subspaces. My guess is that these are the Galois orbits of the Dynkin diagram components, but you lose information passing to diagrams, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, somehting like this does hold in general (for simplicity, I don't want to write out the precise statement).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Can you give a reference where this is spelled out?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. You assume that your group is semisimple simply connected (or simply connected adjoint). Then over an algebraic closure it uniquly decomposes into direct product of simple groups. The Galois group naturally acts on the canonical Dynkin diagram of your group, permitting the connected component of the diagram. From this you can find all what you need (and can) prove.

Comment: Note that if your semismple group anisotropic, your root system is empty.

Comment: In the long paper: Reductive group schemes, by Brian Conrad,  Panor. Synthèses, 42/43, Société Mathématique de France, Paris, 2014, 93–444,   in Chapter 1 (about algebraic groups) you can read about the canonical based root datum of a reductive group. You obtain the canonical Dynkin diagram from the canonical root datum,

Comment: I meant: You obtain the canonical Dynkin diagram from the canonical based root datum,

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Thanks for that reference.  It didn't have what I was looking for, but while tracing through various things I found a survey of Tits that at least has a clear statement of the result I want (see my answer).  I now just have to find a place where it is proved.

Comment: Good! I did not remember that this paper contains the necessary reduction.  Anyway, the required  assertion can be easily proved by the method mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Yes, the statement of Tits was exactly the missing piece I needed to use the method you describe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After looking through the reference that Mikhail Borovoi gave me and tracing through a bunch of back-references, I found a fairly clear description of what holds in the following survey of Tits:

Tits, J.
Classification of algebraic semisimple groups. Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Boulder, Colo., 1965), pp. 33–62, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1966.

A picture of the relevant page is as follows:[image]
Though this survey does not give proofs, it does preface each section with references to the literature.  Presumably I'll be able to find a proof of the above result in those references (though I'd be delighted if someone found it for me, especially since I am not very good at reading French).

Comment: The proposition in the displayed page of Tits is Theorem 24.3 of Milne's book on Algebraic Groups (where it is proved).

Comment: @anon: Wonderful, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think the result you are looking for is Theorem 22.10 in Borel's book on linear algebraic groups, which is as follows (I've omitted a bit of it that is not directly relevant to this question):

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group over a field $k$.  Let $G_i$ ($i \in I$) be the minimal elements among the closed connected normal $k$-subgroups of $G$ of strictly positive dimension.

1. $G$ is the almost direct product of the $G_i$, which are almost $k$-simple.
2. Let $J$ be the set of $i \in I$ for which $\operatorname{rk}_k G_i > 0$.  Then ${{}_k \Phi(G)}$ is the direct sum of the $k$-root systems ${{}_k \Phi(G_j)}$ ($j \in J$), each of which is irreducible.

Comment: Borel's book is such a wonderful reference, isn't it?

Comment: @LSpice: It really does have everything in it.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1172278), for reductive groups, it's probably the best source ([Springer](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4840-4)'s being very close).  But, as soon as you start having to grapple seriously with non-smooth groups (which can happen even if your real interest is in reductive groups—as Abe Simpson said, it happened to me, and one day it'll happen to you!), it's time for [Milne - Algebraic groups](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf) and maybe even for [CGP - Pseudo-reductive groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316092439).

Comment: By the way, TeX note: `\operatorname` does better automatic spacing (and is semantically more precise) than `\text`.  Compare $\text{rk}_k G_i$ `\text{rk}_k G_i` to $\operatorname{rk}_k G_i$ `\operatorname{rk}_k G_i`.  I have edited accordingly.  If you are using such a macro frequently, then you can `\DeclareMathOperator{…}{rk}`, where … is a valid, undefined command name.